# How to prompt the user before closing the browser/tab?

Tags: browser

```
var isRefresh = false;
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 116 || e.which == 17 || e.which == 1)
    {
      isRefresh = true;
    }
});
$(window).bind('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target.href || event.which == 1) 
        $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event) {
  if(!isRefresh){
   var e = window.event;
     if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Are you sure?';
  }

  // For Safari
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Chrome/") != -1){
  return  '';
  }
  else{
    return 'Are you sure?'
  }
 }
});
```

This script is working for closing the tab, F5. According to my requirements prompt should not come for the back button of browser,on press of browser URL. Overall prompt should come only on close of tab.

Answer (score 0):

First most thing you can't control the behaviour of Browsers using Javascript from web page/app.

While `refresh,closing` behaviour browser considered a change of state of webpage which is same for Javascript that why it shows same message.